# Message send timeout for producer sending message to ActiveMQ broker

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to set timeout for sending a message to broker.

I want to send large messages to ActiveMQ broker but I do not want it to take forever, so I was planning to set a timeout while sending message.

Comment: You can try setting 'time to live' for messages

Answer (score 1):

you can set `connection.sendTimeout=some ms` in URI while connecting to broker

Official document for sendTimeout says

- Time to wait on Message Sends for a Response, default value of zero
  indicates to wait forever. Waiting forever allows the broker to have
  flow control over messages coming from this client if it is a fast
  producer or there is no consumer such that the broker would run out
  of memory if it did not slow down the producer. Does not affect Stomp
  clients as the sends are ack'd by the broker. (Since ActiveMQ-CPP
  2.2.1)

here is the documentation https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/configuring

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: connection is what Class? Where does that come from? I cannot find any setTimeout method anywhere

Comment: looks like the variable name has changed in recent versions, you need to use `connection.sendTimeout` and it can be used as follows






new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
    "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616)?connection.sendTimeout=20");

basically it is a part of connection URI, it is not a method